# KVM console with scrollback

Tags: kvm-virtualization, console

I'm running a Linux guest on a Linux host with `kvm -display curses`. I'm not able to scroll back with Shift-*PageUp*. Is there an even simpler display than *curses* which just prints to the host terminal, so I can use the host terminal's scrollback feature?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with a serial console. Instead of

```
kvm -display curses -append '...'
```

I used:

```
kvm -nographic -append '... console=ttyS0 earlyprintk=serial'
```